# Showing a function is analytic on a domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)=f(x+iy)$ is a complex-valued function with continuous first partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ in a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$. Suppose for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ we have that $f_\lambda(z) = f(z) - \lambda z$ has nonnegative Jacobian determinant. I am trying to show that $f$ is analytic on $\Omega$.

If we can show that $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations then we are done because $f$ has continuous first partial derivatives. If we write $f = u + iv$, then we obtain $\det Df_\lambda (x,y) = u_xv_y - \lambda u_x-\lambda v_y+\lambda^2-u_yv_x$. I've tried substituting different values for $\lambda$. If $\lambda = 0$, we have that $u_xv_y-u_yv_x \geq 0$. If $\lambda = i$, we have $(u_xv_y-u_yv_x-1)-i(u_x+v_y)\geq 0$ which means $u_x = -v_y$. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to proceed but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Write the Jacobian of $f$ in terms of the partial derivatives in $z,\bar z$ and show that if those at a point are $a,b$ the Jacobian of $f$ is $|a|^2-|b|^2$, hence the choice of $\lambda=a$ leads to the Jacobian of $f-az$ being $-|b|^2$ so $b=0$ and $f$ is analytic

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am confused how to write the Jacobian in terms of the partial derivatives in $z$ and $\bar{z}$. What would it look like? Also, why wouldn't I proceed by writing the Jacobian the way I initially did?